# Setting up GitHub Actions for deploying a Node.js app on cPanel

Tags: node.js, express, github, github-actions, cpanel

I deployed node.js app on shared hosting that has cPanel using the option "Setup Node.js App", It's super easy to deploy it using this tool from cPanel and I just open it and write the application root, startup file, url and the version of node.js that I want to use. I was searching for a week for a way to use github actions with my cPanel but I didn't reach to something useful. I want to make a github repo and link it to my cpanel and when I push any new changes it take these changes and deploy it automatically. Anyone can help?

I couldn't find resources talking about doing this thing on the internet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can check out  this [Github Repo](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action). This might be helpful to you as It outlines a way to upload your nodejs files to your cpanel file manager whenever you push. In terms of restarting your server you might want to use a package like pm2 for that

Comment: @OgurinkaBenjamin I already using this repo right now it's only uploading the files of the project, but I can't do somethings like install, start, stop or restart the node server. And it's shared hosting so I don't have the ability to add any packages to help me to do that.

Comment: @SeifAhmed, I haven’t tried this before, but here’s a what you can attempt to do… if you have Shell access, you can try to add an ssh authentication to your deployment workflow and try to restart the app after files have been uploaded. It might take a bit more work, but should work. You can also read up on my earlier suggestions of using PM2